# how to add service separately?

Tags: c#

```
public App()
{
    m_host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();       
}    

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args = null)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .AddManager()
                    .AddStores()
                    .AddViewModels()
                    .AddViews();
}
```

These services are added initially.

Can I add `.AddServices` after `CreateHostBuilder().Build();`

or outside of

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args = null)
```

Comment: `.UseStartup` ?

Comment: @Llama `.UseStartup` allow me to add **.AddService** after the window form appear?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that this wasn't web. I'm not sure `.UseStartup` exists in your context. Either way, it wouldn't allow that even if it did exist, since you will have already built the service container at that point. Can you provide more information about your reason for doing this?

Comment: @Llama I'm doing validation now. If the application is not connected to the server, then the application will show the Home UI first. But now it stopped at SQL connection. The SQL connection included inside the class **AddServiceHostBuilder**. So I need AddService after the window form appears(Even if the UI is empty because the home window form needs the sqlconnection).